# Add a new line between dependencies via google sort pom plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way to add a new line between each dependency via the google sort pom plugin or any other plugin.

Current POM, sorted via google sort pom plugin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to achieve

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

My current pom plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${com.google.code.sortpom}</version>
    <configuration>
        <predefinedSortOrder>custom_1</predefinedSortOrder>
        <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
        <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
        <sortProperties>false</sortProperties>
        <createBackupFile>false</createBackupFile>
        <lineSeparator>\r\n</lineSeparator>
        <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
        <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
        <nrOfIndentSpace>-1</nrOfIndentSpace>
        <verifyFail>Warn</verifyFail>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>sort</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the maven-sortpom-plugin does not have an automatic way of inserting blank lines between dependencies.

However, if you have a empty line between two existing dependencies, the plugin will not remove the line during sorting since you use the configuration option `<keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>`

Answer (score 0):

#### Its just an XML file

Just use your IDE's built in XML formatter to format the `pom.xml` file however you want. Both Eclipse and Intellij IDEA have formatters for XML files.

Comment: In eclipse I couldn't figure out the part which does this. Here is where I was Window -> Preferences -> XML -> Xml Files -> Editor